# show / hide divs based on multiple checkbox values in the data atrribute, multiple values data attribute

Tags: javascript

I am hoping to make a product comparison page with JavaScript which has different groups of checkboxes, enabling the end-user to select what he/she wants to have visible. For example, the options for product can be multiple. Like red, blue color. The size is medium and has battery and solar power. And then it should only show the product with the checkbox selected values.

```html
<h4 class="heading-primary">color</h4>

<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="red" /> red</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="white" /> white</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="blue" /> blue</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="orange" /> orange</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="green" /> green</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="color" value="purple" /> purple</label><br/>
</ul>
<h4 class="heading-primary">size</h4>
<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="size" value="small" /> small</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="size" value="medium" /> medium</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="size" value="large" /> large</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="size" value="xl" />xl</label><br/>
</ul>
<h4 class="heading-primary">External power</h4>
<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="power" value="battery" /> Battery</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="power" value="solar" /> Solar</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="power" value="inducive" /> Inductive</label><br>
</ul>

<h4 class="heading-primary">casing </h4>
<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="casing" value="car" />
   Car </label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="casing" value="key" /> Key fob</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="casing" value="oem" /> Oem</label><br>
</ul>

<h4 class="heading-primary">Sensors</h4>
<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="acceleration" /> Acceleration</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="Temperature" /> Temperature</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="Humidity" /> Humidity</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="airquality" /> Air quality</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="magneto" /> Compass / Magneto</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="audio" /> Audio</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="barometer" /> Barometer / Altitude</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="distance" /> Distance</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="pir" />  Movement (PIR)</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="co2" /> Co2</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="sensor" value="ligth" />  Light sensor</label><br>
</ul>

<h4 class="heading-primary">External connectors</h4>
<ul>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="extconnector" value="yes" /> Yes</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" data-filter-type="extconnector" value="no" /> No</label><br>
</ul>

<div class="products">

  <div class="productItem" data-color="red white blue orange purple green" data-size="small medium large" data-power="battery" extconnector="yes">Module 178<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="white" data-size="small medium large" data-power="inductive battery" extconnector="yes">Module R9B3<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="white" data-size="small medium large" data-power="powerC" extconnector="yes">Module 186<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="orange" data-size="small medium large" data-power="inductive battery" extconnector="no">Module 187/R9A11<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="orange" data-size="small medium large" data-power="inductive battery" extconnector="no">Module 3001<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="orange" data-size="medium" data-power="inductive battery solar" extconnector="no">Module 231<br>
  </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="inductive battery" extconnector="no"> Module medium </div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2001</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2011</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2016</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2206</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2207</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 2208</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no"> Module 1025</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no">Module 206</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no">Module 3101</div>
  <div class="productItem" data-color="purple" data-size="medium" data-power="battery" extconnector="no">MOdule power</div>
</div>
```

I have Googled all of Stack Overflow. and I've found several good examples of JavaScript for selecting checkboxes and showing/hiding div elements the way I would like.

The trouble that I have is that I want to put more than 1 term in the data attribute, and then only show the search items selected by the checkboxes.

I fear this is more difficult and should be done server-side?

```html
<div class="productItem" data-color="red white blue orange purple green" data-size="small medium large" data-power="battery" extconnector="yes">Module 178<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the link to the answer that you liked but you want to improve? And how do you generate the HTML of the products and add filter type? do you have an array or something?

Answer (score 0):

Give every div an array of tags. Then, for every div, loop through the selected checkboxes. If there is a checkbox selected which is NOT in that divs tags, hide that div.

Example: one of the divs has tags "red" and "small". The selected checkboxes are "red", "small", and "battery". Since the div does not have "battery" in its tags, hide it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).